# OpenStreetMap and floorplan image interaction and coordinate conversion

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis, openstreetmap

Premise: I need to build this feature for an open source application.

I want to allow users to upload images of floorplans and specify coordinates of objects on these floorplans.

In a specific common use case, users will need to be able to convert floorplan coordinates to geographic (latitude & longitude) coordinates, with good enough precision (not rocket science, but either not totally wrong).

**The question is**: on a high level, how can I accomplish this? 
What kind of existing educational resources can I find about this subject?

My idea is to let users place/rotate/adapt the floorplan images on the geographic map, so that floorplan coordinates can be converted to geographic coordinates in some way.

The only good javascript open source project I found that deals with floorplan is [d3-floorplan](https://github.com/dciarletta/d3-floorplan).

Any other suggestion will be very useful.

PS: I know it's a broad question, but I know of no other good place to ask this question than here on SO, I think this kind of question has a good value for people that will find this kind of information from future searches.

Comment: As you say, this is a pretty broad question and SA is about implementation details. If you can't tell what you tried and where you failed, it's hard for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to pick similar points to the not aligned image / floorplan and on a geographic aligned map (aka 'passpoints'). The processing with n passpoints is usually done at server side and the client downloads the resulting aligned plan as WMS / TMS layer to Leaflet or OL3 JS.

Some existing services: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vertical_Aerial_Photographs

P.S: Be aware, that this covers legal aspects, too. So are you allowed to clone the georeference and does it fit well enough etc...